# Android: send an email with an image from an ImageView

Tags: android, android-imageview, email-attachments

I'm new here on stackoverflow. I have a little problem with my Android app, expecially with an ImageView that triggers an event on tap. This event opens an email client with some pre-written text and it should attach the image of the Image. I already know that the image should be converted into a bitmap before, then compressed and send it to the email client, but unfortunatly I'm not an Android/Java expert so I can't find how to do that. This is the code of the email method:

*new code below*

Where I have to replace "String imageURI = null;" with what the email needs as image. Thank you all!

EDIT:

I managed to edit my code to this, that gives no errors:

```
public void sendMail(ImageView image){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    int imageURI = R.drawable.img1;

    i.setType("text/plain");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"destinatario@globelife.biz"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Oggetto");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Globelife");
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    i.setType("image/jpeg");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/"+imageURI));


    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail..."));
    } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
        Toast.makeText(Test01Activity.this, "Non sono presenti app per l'invio di e-mails.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

But I need to change "int imageURI = R.drawable.img1;" to "int imageURI = ImageView.src;" or something like that

Comment: the image you want to send is save on your local SDCard or it is coming from internet?

Comment: The image is in the drawable folder of the app

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashImageView);
Drawable d =iv.getBackground();
BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
Bitmap bitmap = bitDw.getBitmap();
File  mFile = savebitmap(bitmap);
```

and then

```
   Uri u = null;
   u = Uri.fromFile(mFile);

   Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   emailIntent.setType("image/*");
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Hello...");
   // + "\n\r" + "\n\r" +
   // feed.get(Selectedposition).DETAIL_OBJECT.IMG_URL
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your tsxt here");
   emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, u);
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));
```

and `savebitmap` method

```
    private File savebitmap(Bitmap bmp) {
  String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
  OutputStream outStream = null;
  File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, temp + ".png");
  if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
   file = new File(extStorageDirectory, temp + ".png");
  }

  try {
   outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
   outStream.flush();
   outStream.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   return null;
  }
  return file;
 }
```

Comment: It says on the last line of code ("i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, bis );") the error "The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, ByteArrayInputStream)"

Comment: You code gives no compilation errors but when I tap on the image to send the e-mail it gives a NullPointerException on the method sendMail(ImageView image) (the one we are working on). I'm trying right now to search what's wrong..

Comment: LogCat:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at it.neoweb.test.Test01Activity.sendMail(Test01Activity.java:120)
at it.neoweb.test.Test01Activity.onContextItemSelected(Test01Activity.java:92)
at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2199)

Comment: I found the error, just change Drawable d = iv.getBackground();
 to Drawable d = iv.getDrawable(); - hope this helps!

Comment: oh you are setting image `src` not the background ?

Comment: Yeah, and that worked perfecly. Thank you for your code anyway, it really helped out a lot

Comment: one small doubt is the save bitmap method saving the image to the external sd card in the phone???

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
String[] recipients={"destinatario@domain.com"};
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, recipients);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Oggetto");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Testo");
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
intent.setType("image/png");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(“file///sdcard/Images/your_image.jpg”));//or you can pass the path of your image
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send mail"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
i.setType("image/jpg");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Pictures/
image.jpg"));
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score -1):

//re move the `String imageURI=null;`

```
public void sendMail(ImageView image){
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

Uri pngImageUri = Uri.parse(image);


i.setType("image/png");//change here with image/png
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"destinatario@domain.com"});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Oggetto");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "Testo");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pngImageUri);
```

Comment: Hello again, I'm trying to use "Uri.parse(image);" but it says
"The method parse(String) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView)"

Comment: then use 'Uri.fromFile(image);'

Comment: It says the same error, now with File ("The method fromFile(File) in the type Uri is not applicable for the arguments (ImageView)")

Comment: chek here: http://blogingtutorials.blogspot.in/2010/12/send-email-with-attached-file-in.html