# Get the image from ImageView

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap, imageview, email-attachments

I have a image view where it show the image i took from camera

this is how i take the image :

```
    btnImg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(i, 0);
        }
    });
```

this is how i give the image to ImageView:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

and i want to get the image so that i can attach it in email

Comment: I think that you do not pass Bitmap.

You can check in `onActivityResult` to add a bitmap to ImageView. you will get null pointer

Comment: Is there a way to save the image in a variable or something like that?

Comment: You can get the base64 String representation of the image or upload the image to some server and use the image link sent by the server

Comment: how can i get the String representation of image? is something like that : <code>bitmap.toString()</code> @NongthonbamTonthoi

Comment: For that see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9224056/android-bitmap-to-base64-string

Comment: this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11428189/android-send-an-email-with-an-image-from-an-imageview

Answer (score 0):

In `onActivityResult` you can receive file path

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri imageURI = data.getData();
    String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(imageURI, projection, null, null, null);
    int column_index = cursor
            .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String filePath=cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

After getting `filepath` you can attach to email.